# Multithreaded Webserver in C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I want to do a multithreaded Webserver with scheduling and synchronization in C++.This is an assignment problem and I am not asking the code.I have done till the socket connection in server but I dont know how to proceed.I just want some hints or flow for the program.

Here are the few questions I have

1) I have done till socket accept().So when new connection comes I have to fork() and then close the connections of the child process.Is that right?

2) How must I make sure the program is synchronized wth so many threads running?

3) I must have 2 thread pools.1 pool of workers and in the other 2,1 each for acepting connection and inserting the request to ready queue.How can this be done?

I am not asking the code.I just need some hints and guidance.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you mean multithreaded or multiprocess? `fork()` will spawn a different process, not just a thread.

Comment: I am looking for multithreaded webserver.

Comment: If you have to ask "How must I make sure the program is synchronized with so many threads running?", you might be a bit out of your depth.  That's pretty much *the whole problem* in threading.  And there's no universal answer to the question; it's very case-by-case.

Comment: Let me put it this way.Can I do it using semaphores?

Comment: You could do it with semaphores, mutexes, fifos, sockets...the list just keeps going.  Anything that can block, can be used to implement some form of synchronization.  And what you use depends on your specific case.

Comment: can you give me a flow for the program? I have trouble in finding where to start.

Comment: And that's why this is too big a question to ask on SO.  That's the part you have to come up with.  We're here to help with the little details, but we can't design the thing for you.  That's also why i was saying "you might be a bit out of your depth".

Comment: As far as a starting point, though...consider one thread looping, doing nothing but `accept()`ing new connections and passing them off to a pool of worker threads that do the real work of handling a request.

Comment: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#simpleserver may be a good starting point

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting course work , if you get you head around this one a lot of concepts will become clear namely concurrency and one of its major use cases I.e. networking!

I used the following article myself to get a quick summary of my options in network concurrency in Linux

http://m.linuxjournal.com/content/three-ways-web-server-concurrency?page=0,0

This article give very high level intros to concepts tha thou will need  like copy on write for forked processes and as a result separate address spaces negating sync in certain cases, once you have read this you will have more specific question that you can as once you start getting your hands dirty starting with the code in this article.